# how to specify websocket encoder and decoder to simple class

Tags: java, netbeans, websocket

I am writing a simple websocket application. In this I separate out the message sending functionality. More clearly `onOpen, onClose, onMessage, onError` etc methods are placed in the class which annotated with `@ServerEndpoint` i.e.

```
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/test")
public class TestEndpoint {

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) throws IOException {
    }

    @OnMessage
    public String echo(String message) {
    }

    @OnError
    public void onError(Throwable t) {
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session) {
    }
}
```

And I want to give responsibility of sending message **object** to the class `MessageSender`, i.e.

```
public class MessageSender {

  /**
  *
  * This method will take care of sending messages object
  */
  public void sendMessage(){
  }
}
```

so MessageSender class should make use of websocket `Encoder` and `Decoder` class but as per my knowledge we can use `Encoders` and `Decoders` only in `@ServerEndpoint` annotation

like,

@ServerEndpoint(value = "/test", encoder = Encoder.class, decoders = Decoder.class)

is there any way to use encoder and decoder for simple class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Encoder` and `Decoder` will be applied to the created `Session` object, so if you will pass it to the `MessageSender` class and then do something like `session.getBasicRemote().sendObject(…)`, it will use the same set of encoders which are defined on the `@ServerEndpoint` annotation.